# What is the easiest way of returning a generic subtype when all the subtypes have identical constructor methods in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have 3 case classes:

1. `Employee`
2. `Creator`, which extends `Employee`
3. `Administrator`, which extends `Creator`, and is responsible for changing any `Employee`'s role:

```scala
case class Employee (id: UUID, companyId: UUID)

case class Creator (override val id: UUID, override val companyId: UUID) 
extends Employee(id, companyId)

final case class Administrator (override val id: UUID, override val companyId: UUID) 
extends Creator(id, companyId) {
  def changeRole(employee: Employee): ??? = {
    ???
  }
}
```

The `changeRole` is responsible for taking in any `Employee`, and promoting or demoting
it.

---

How can I specify which role `employee` should be promoted/demoted to? I came up with this:

```scala
def changeRole[E <: Employee](employee: Employee): E = {
  ???
}
```

So, I should be able to use it as such:

```scala
administrator.changeRole[Administrator](employee) // returns Administrator, the employee is promoted to Administrator
```

However, how am I supposed to implement `changeRole`? I need a way to somehow return an `E`, whether it is an `Creator`, `Administrator`, or whatever role.

---

## Possible solutions

1. ###### Use a `TypeTag` and `asInstanceOf`

```scala
def changeRole[E <: Employee: TypeTag](employee: Employee): E = {
  val newEmployee = typeOf[E] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Creator]       => Creator(employee.id, employee.companyId)
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Administrator] => Administrator(employee.id, employee.companyId)
  }

  newEmployee.asInstanceOf[E]
}
```

That does solve the issue, however `asInstanceOf` is considered a bad practice, and definitely not type-safe.

2. ###### Requiring a "Factory" type class for `E`

```scala
def changeRole[E <: Employee: EmployeeBuilder](employee: Employee): E = {
  val builder = implicitly[EmployeeBuilder[E]]
  builder.build(employee.id, employee.companyId)
}
```

where `EmployeeBuilder` is:

```scala
trait EmployeeBuilder[T <: Employee] {
  def build(id: UUID, companyId: UUID): T
}
```

Type-safe, but still tedious. I have to define a `Builder` for every single role, and all it does is it calls the `apply` method of the role's `case class`:

```scala
object Creator {
  // the builder for the Creator role
  implicit val creatorBuilder: EmployeeBuilder[Creator] = (id: UUID, companyId: UUID) => Creator(id, companyId)
}

// the rest of the builders for every single case class
```

Also, all of the `case class`es' constructor methods take in the same arguments: `id` and `companyId`.

Is there any way I can just derive an `Apply` typeclass or something like that so I don't have to explicitly create a builder typeclass for every single `Employee`?

Is there a better way for doing what I'm trying to do here? Thanks.

Comment: I would rather only have `Employee` and the role be a property of the class instead of using subtyping for that.

Comment: So after a change, you'll have two Employees with the same id? That seems questionable. Maybe all Employees have-a Role, which has multiple subtypes? Then a Role can change without identity changing.